# Browser HTML Linkedin URLScheme opens app but fails to open profile or company page

Tags: android, html, linkedin-api

I'm trying, on Android 9, from an app web browser (Opera, Chrome) to use an HTML link (with linkedin URLScheme) to open linkedin app with view on my company page. I'm not able to achieve it. None of the answers in StackOverflow I've read worked, even though the endpoints I used were coming from StackOverflow.

I've tried that

- `<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/[company_name]"></a>`
- `<a href="linkedin://www.linkedin.com/company/[company_name]"></a>`
- `<a href="linkedin://linkedin.com/company/[company_name]"></a>`
- `<a href="linkedin://profile/company/[company_id]"></a>`
- `<a href="linkedin://profile/company/[company_name]"></a>`
- `<a href="linkedin://profile/[company_id]"></a>`
- `<a href="linkedin://profile/[company_name]"></a>`
- `<a href="linkedin://company/[company_id]"></a>`
- `<a href="linkedin://company/[company_name]"></a>`
- `<a href="linkedin://[company_id]"></a>`
- `<a href="linkedin://[company_name]"></a>`
- And even more exotic url (profile?id=...) and so on.

I have 2 results depending of the link (except https which change current web page):

- or it don't do anything and I stay on web browser
- or it open the homescreen of linkedin app but not the company page

How can I achieve a URL that opens linkedin app on company page?